# Open Mapping Theorem proof

Tags: complex-analysis

In my notes on complex analysis we have this version of the Open Mapping Theorem

> The image of an open set under a non-constant holomorphic map is open.

The proof begins by stating that it is enough to show that the image of an open disc is open under a non-constant holomorphic map.

I do not understand why this is the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every open set is an union of open discs. If you prove that the image of an open disc is open, then, for every open set $U$ we have
$$U=\bigcup_{i\in I}D_i$$
$$f(U)=f\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}D_i\right)=\bigcup_{i\in I}f(D_i)$$
So if each $f(D_i)$ is open, then $f(U)$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

since the open discs form a basis of the topology, every open set can be written as the union of open discs.

So lets assume we have an Open $U$ then $U= \bigcup_{i\in I} D_i$ for $D_i$ open disks (observe that $I$ is an arbitrary index set!). Now $$f(U)=f(\bigcup_{i\in I} D_i)=\bigcup_{i\in I}f(D_i)$$
and so since the righthandside is open, the lefthandside is as well.

Furthermore, since every open disk is open we have that a map $f:\mathbb{C} \to X$ is open if and only if every open disk gets sent to an open disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can cover any non-empty open set of the plane by open discs. Then any point in the image of this open set will be in the image of such a disc, and therefore will have an open neighborhood included in the image.

Comment: "cover by" is not what you need here; in fact you can cover _any_ subset of the plane by open disks...

Comment: You are right, what I meant is that such an open set can be written as the union of such open discs.